# Not able to run selenium on jenkins linux

Tags: linux, jenkins, selenium-chromedriver

```
 Map<String, Object> prefs = new HashMap<String, Object>();
// Put this into prefs map to switch off browser notification
prefs.put("profile.default_content_setting_values.notifications", 1); // as it helps in enabling web-push notifications in a smaller way.

// Create chrome options to set this prefs
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.setExperimentalOption("prefs", prefs); // Forcing Chrome to Allow Push Notifications
options.addArguments("incognito");// opening in incognito mode as notifications can be handled easily

File file=new File("src/main/resources/selenium/chromedriverlinux");
System.out.println(file.getAbsolutePath());
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", file.getAbsolutePath());
// System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","/usr/local/lib/node_modules/chromedriver/78.0.3904.70/chromedriver");

options.setExperimentalOption("useAutomationExtension", false);
options.addArguments("--headless", "--disable-gpu", "--window-size=1920,1200","--ignore-certificate-errors");
// options.addArguments("--proxy-server='direct://'");
// options.addArguments("--proxy-bypass-list=*");
options.addArguments("--no-sandbox");
options.addArguments("--disable-dev-shm-usage");

driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
```

> Please protect ports used by ChromeDriver and related test frameworks
>   to prevent access by malicious code.
>   ***** Error CreateOrderTest_Family_10000_0to40 test has failed ***** org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: Chrome failed
>   to start: exited abnormally.   (unknown error: DevToolsActivePort file
>   doesn't exist)   (The process started from chrome location
>   /usr/local/bin/chrome is no longer running, so ChromeDriver is
>   assuming that Chrome has crashed.)   (Driver info:
>   chromedriver=80.0.3987.16
>   (320f6526c1632ad4f205ebce69b99a062ed78647-refs/branch-heads/3987@{#185}),platform=Linux
>   4.13.0-1011-azure x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)

Comment: Please provide more details what are you trying to do, what's your environment and what leads to the error.

Comment: I am trying to run on jenkins . os linux